# Search Invoice Tablle to find Invoices with Quantity >0 and <0

Tags: sql

I am searching Invoice Itemized Table for Invoices with Quantity having >0 and <0. Invoice Itemized table contains details of all the items in an Invoice. How can I write a query that gives all the invoices that have Quantity of items >0 and <0.

Comment: Add the schema of the involved tables in your question..

Comment: Ever heared of the not-equal-operator <>?

Comment: I tried using common table expressions and it is taking long time to execute the query leading to time out of the report.

Comment: Its not about <> operator..I want to search invoices that have both positive and negative transactions in an invoice.The table stores every line item in the database with same invoice number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this?  This uses two queries. The first finds all the invoices with Negative Quantities.  Then it APPLY's the second query to find from that list of invoices only those that also have positive quantities.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  PosNegInvoices.InvoiceID 
FROM ItemizedInvoice AS NegInvoices
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    InvoiceID
  FROM ItemizedInvoice 
  WHERE InvoiceID = NegInvoices.InvoiceID
  AND Quantity > 0
) AS PosNegInvoices
WHERE NegInvoices.Quantity < 0
```

Here is another version that uses CTEs:

```
WITH NegInvoices AS
(
  SELECT
    InvoiceID
  FROM ItemizedInvoice
  WHERE Quantity < 0
),
PosInvoices AS 
(
  SELECT
    InvoiceID
  FROM ItemizedInvoice
  WHERE Quantity > 0
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  PosInvoices.InvoiceID
FROM NegInvoices 
JOIN PosInvoices
ON NegInvoices.InvoiceID = PosInvoices.InvoiceID
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the same CTE that you have advised but its taking around 15 minutes execute the query. I am trying to improve the query. Infact its huge data with detailed invoices.

Comment: What are your indexes?  Having a non-clustered index on the items table that included the InvoiceID and Quantity might help.  Infact you could even create a filtered index for each of the negative and positive conditions, depending on the version, edition of SQL Server.